# Forms collections sub-entity

Tags: php, symfony

I try to make a form but I block a point.

I have a quiz that her several questions which themselves have several answers.

I would like to make a general form that shows me all the questions associated with the quiz answers.
I can neither retrieve the questions / answers associated with the quiz or to display them.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\FrontendQuestionQuizzMultipleType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FrontendQuizzType extends AbstractType
{

    public  function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('quizzquestions', 'collection', array('type' => new FrontendQuestionQuizzMultipleType() ) )
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'frontend_appbundle_quizz';
    }
}
```

FrontendQuestionQuizzMultipleType

```
 <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use AppBundle\Entity\QuizzResponseRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FrontendQuestionQuizzMultipleType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $options;

    public  function __construct() {
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content')
            ->add('quizzresponses','entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\QuizzResponse', 'by_reference' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'required' => false));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\QuizzQuestion',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'frontend_appbundle_quizzquestion';
    }
}
```

Twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
                    {% for question in form.quizzquestions %}
                        DO SOMETHING
                    {% endfor %}
                {{ form_end(form) }}
```

I want the final rendering is:

Question 1: Question 1 Title

Radio button options 1 Answer Question 1

Radio button choices 2 Answer Question 1

Question 2: Question 2 Title

Radio button options 1 Answer Question 2

Radio button choices 2 Answer Question 2

etc ...

Submit Button

Thank you in advance for your help